# Issues with returnJson not returning html?

Tags: plugin-development, controller

Im running in to issues with returnJson not returning html or just returning and empty object:

```
$userHtml = craft()->logic->renderSiteMacro('_macros/elements', 'listing', $args);

$this->returnJson(array(
     'success' => true,
     'existing' => $userHtml
));
```

The return JSON is always:

```
{"success":true,"existing":{}}
```

I have double checked the html output exists and the issue persists:

- Whether returning a simple string or large chunk of html
- And with and without single quotes
- When renderSiteMacro functions runs the code through the raw filter and not

Answer (score 4):

It appears whitespace was the cause here, just running a quick whitespace filer on the return value resolved the issue:

```
$userHtml = craft()->logic->renderSiteMacro('_macros/elements', 'listing', $args);

$userHtml = preg_replace('~>\\s+<~m', '><', $userHtml);

$this->returnJson(array(
    'success' => true,
    'existing' => $userHtml
));
```